# Mouse trouble in 16.04

Tags: lubuntu, 16.04, mouse-pointer

I am having trouble with my mouse in Lubuntu 16.04. After updating the OS every time I put my laptop to sleep, and when i log in again my mouse cursor vanishes. I have to reboot the system for it to work. Is there any other way to rectify this issue if so plz do tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could this be the same that is mentioned at
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1568604
?

One workaround until a fix is released seems to be to hit Ctrl+Alt+F1 then Ctrl+Alt+F7.

A Debian user reported that running `xset dpms force off` and then hitting a key also worked.

---

This was the most pleasant workaround for me:

Put the following into `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-workaround-mouse-cursor.conf`:

```
[Seat:*]
session-cleanup-script=/usr/local/bin/VTswitch
```

And the following into `/usr/local/bin/VTswitch`:

```
#!/bin/sh
n=$(fgconsole) || exit 1
case "$n" in
    [0-9]) 
        /bin/chvt 1
        /bin/chvt "$n"
        sleep 1
        ;;
    *) echo "error from $0; fgconsole gave $n" >/tmp/VTswitch.log
esac
```

And run `chmod +x /usr/local/bin/VTswitch`. After a restart, you should no longer lose the cursor on suspend/lock.

Comment: the mentioned link is the  same as what  the issue i have. Both the workarounds are possible and they  do work in the Lubuntu 16.04 i have.. Thanks for the links and workaorund