# Disappearing mouse cursor, when upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, mouse, 16.04

I recently tried upgrading from Lubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 LTS on my old Toshiba laptop. Everything seemed to go all right, but whenever my system would go to sleep, my mouse cursor disappears shortly after I logged back in.

I've looked at the various forums on the subject, and from what I can tell, this seems to be a common problem when updating from one version of Lubuntu to another.

I tried switching to Xubuntu, upgrading from 15.10 to 16.04 LTS to see if i could replicate the problem on another variation of Ubuntu, and I did.  Again the same disappearing mouse as with Lubuntu.

I tried installing a fresh version of 16.04 LTS, but there must be some glitch in the installer, because my computer locked up after install, and would not boot any operating system after that.

I had to use a Windows XP install disk to completely reformat my Hard Drive, before I could reinstall 15.10 again to make it boot (yes I tried 16.04 LTS first, but ran into the same problem). My laptop is old, and cannot handle full Ubuntu past 13.10, without becoming extremely sluggish, so I need a lighter alternative.

So far, all I've seen are temporary fixes, like a soft relaunch through the command line, it works, but that closes out my applications, and I lose my work.

I'm in need of a permanent fix. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this is the same problem as yours?: https://askubuntu.com/questions/761229/mouse-trouble-in-16-04

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Alt+F1 then Ctrl +Alt+F7 brings the cursor back on my system. It's not a fix, but it doesn't close your apps.

Answer (score 0):

very funny ! Terminal is a way to solve vanishing mouse problem!   Here is another way : Reset Monitor to anything other than what was set in install! It worked for me on a Ubuntu 16.04,maybe on this Lubuntu 16.04 LTS also !